# Ionic2 with Meteor

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a problem using Meteor in an Ionic2 project.
The project itself should run, as it is a clone of the Meteor-tutorial:
`git clone https://github.com/Urigo/Ionic2CLI-Meteor-WhatsApp`

When I start the Meteor server I get this

```
=> Started proxy.                             
server/publications.ts (24, 10): Property 'publishComposite' does not exist on type 'typeof Meteor'.
server/main.ts (14, 28): Property '_options' does not exist on type 'typeof Accounts'.
server/main.ts (51, 14): Property 'createUserWithPhone' does not exist on type 'typeof Accounts'.
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

Then I start the ionic app with `ionic serve` and get this in the terminal

```
Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729
Watching: www/**/*, !www/lib/**/*, !www/**/*.map
√ Running dev server:  http://localhost:8100
```

When I open the App I get this error in the browser's console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8100/sockjs/info?cb=_07sz35uj7
```

As I understand it means that it tries to grab data from meteor but couldn't reach it. When I open the URL in the browser manually and change the port to `3000` I get back a message from meteor.

**I found two hints on Google:**

1) start the ionic app without livereload
`ionic serve --nolivereload`

2) to set `__meteor_runtime_config__` to the correct `URL:PORT`

But hint 1 doesn't work and for hint 2 I have no idea where to place it.

While writing this I found out, that in the file `node_modules/meteor-client-side/meteor-runtime-config.js` the correct port is defined by

```
__meteor_runtime_config__ = {};
__meteor_runtime_config__.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
```

So it looks like hint 2 is also already done.
Why is it still trying to reach the meteor server on wrong port, or is there maybe another problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved it on my own again.
I had to add those lines of code to the `index.html` file of my ionic2 project:

```
<script>
    __meteor_runtime_config__ = {
      DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL: 'http://localhost:3000'
    };
</script>
```

No idea, why the config in the `node_modules/meteor-client-side/meteor-runtime-config.js` file is ignored.

**Edit:** Looks like there was a bug that is fixed in version 1.3.5
https://github.com/idanwe/meteor-client-side/issues/28#issuecomment-263252756